# Azure Logic App - Receive file from http request

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have an ASP.Net handler that returns a PDF report. I want the Azure Logic App to request the file and then add it to an e-mail as an attachment.

When I try to do this through an HTTP request I get the following error:

> BadRequest. Http request failed as there is an error: 'Error while copying content to a stream.'

If I make the request with a browser I get a HTTP 200 response and it works. See request/response headers from chrome and fiddler.

I'm sure I could solve this with an Azure Function to get the file blob and pass it to the e-mail stage but it appears in the documentation that Logic Apps can handle streams and base64 encode. Am I missing something here?

[image: chrome network tab]

Comment: Is your file stored as a blob?

Comment: I don't think logic app supports it (to be confirmed by a logic app expert) . In the past I managed to work around this problem by sending the file as base64 encoded body then the logic app will pick up the file content correctly.

Comment: @GeorgeChen the response streams the file. I was just referring to the 'Body' as blob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with the following a static result in an HTTP request to mimic the HTTP request/stream as much as possible. I guess it comes down to that you need to design the body of the stream in a way the includes content and content-type like I did below with my mockup HTTP request

[image: static request]

pdf content

[image: static request setup1]

content-type: application/pdf and application/octet-stream worked
[image: static request setup2]

Send and email action:

[image]

Sent email
[image: result]

Outlook result:

[image]

Comment: I might have misunderstood the issue but I hope it helps somehow.

Comment: Thanks @AdAstra, this set me off on the write path. As soon as I converted my handler to return a JSON object rather than stream the file directly I was able to get it working pretty quick.

I also ended up following your practice of including any other attributes like filename in the object rather than adding headers to the response object as I was struggling to access them in Logic Apps afterwards.